# PHP add subdomain to a url string

Tags: php, string, url

I have been trying to create a function that takes the url string and adds a subdomain string to the url string. Am sorry if this is too easy for you, I want to redirect to the user subdomain once they login from the main site that's why am looking for a way to 'inject' the subdomain.

e.g.

```
function inject_subdomain($url,$subdomain)

}

$url = 'hxxps://abc.com/';
inject_subdomain($url,'ninja');
//returns 'hxxps://ninja.abc.com/'

$url = 'hxxps://www.abc.com/';
inject_subdomain($url,'ninja');
//returns 'hxxps://ninja.abc.com/'

$url = 'hxxp://www.abc.co.uk/'; 
inject_subdomain($url,'ninja');
//returns 'hxxp://ninja.abc.co.uk/'
```

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: You do need to try something. SO isn't a free code service.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson sorry about that, new to the service. I shall post my attempts next time. Not what I intended. I just knew the solution was so simple I just needed to be pointed to the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Abdus Sattar's answer...It pointed me to the right direction...below is the solution I was looking for...

```
function inject_subdomain($url,$subdomain){

    strstr($url,'www') ? 
      $url_parts = explode('://www',$url):
      $url_parts = explode('://',$url);

   return $url_parts[0].'://'.$subdomain.'.'.$url_parts[1];

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
function inject_subdomain($url,$subdomain)
   $url_parts = explode('://www',$url);
   $url_parts2 = explode('://',$url);
   if(count($url_parts)){
     return $url_parts[0].$subdomain.$url_parts[1];
    }
   return $url_parts2[0].$subdomain.$url_parts2[1];

}
```

Comment: You're missing the functions opening brace and the `if`-statement will _always_ return true (since explode will always return at least one array item).

Comment: @Abdus 
 
Thanks. I've solved it thanks to an idea I got from your code. I have edited your solution.